# Showing that a local ring is a DVR

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Question is 2.24 from Fulton:

Let $V=\mathbb{A}^1$, $\Gamma(V)=k[X]$, $K=k(V)=k(X)$.

(a) For each $a\in k=V$, show that $\mathscr{O}_a(V)$ is a DVR with uniformizing parameter $t=X-a$.

(b) Show that $\mathscr{O}_\infty=\{F/G\in k(X)\mid\deg(G)\geq\deg(F)\}$ is also a DVR, with uniformizing parameter $t=1/X$.

---

Unpacking everything I know
$\mathscr{O}_a(V)=\{\frac{\overline{f}}{\overline{g}}\mid f,g\in\Gamma(V),g(a)\neq0\}$. It is known by previous work that $\mathscr{O}_a(V)$ is a Noetherian local domain, so what remains is to show that $\mathfrak{m}$ (the maximal ideal) is principal, and that every nonzero element $z\in\mathscr{O}_a(V)$ can be written as $z=u(X-a)^n$ for unit $u$ and

$n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$.

I'm following work from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1221197, but the discrete valuation provided doesn't make any sense to me since $z=\frac{c_r(X-a)^r+\ldots+c_n(X-a)^n}{b_s(X-a)^s+\ldots+b_m(X-a)^m}$ is clearly not defined at $X=a$, so $z\not\in\mathscr{O}_a(V)$. Any help finishing this proof?

Comment: The discrete valuation there in part (1) is defined for all elements of $k(V)$, and restricts naturally to $\mathcal{O}_{V,a}\subset k(V)$.

Comment: @KReiser Sorry, I'm unsure what you mean. My hangup with the approach I've (and the other poster, linked) tried is that $z=\frac{\overline{f}}{\overline{g}}=\frac{c_r(X-a)^r+\ldots+c_n(X-a)^n}{b_s(X-a)^s+\ldots+b_m(X-a)^m}$ confronts the fact that $g(a)=0$, and hence $z\not\in\mathscr{O}_a(V)$, so why are we talking about it?

Comment: $g(a)$ need not equal zero. Consider $s=0$, for instance. Or you may be able to rewrite $z=\frac{f'}{g'}$ with $g'(a)\neq 0$, like if $z=\frac{(X-a)^2}{(X-a)}$. The reason we talk about it is because any valuation on a DVR extends naturally to a valuation on the field of fractions of a DVR, and a DVR is uniquely recoverable from a field with a valuation as the set of all elements of nonnegative valuation (this statement might require a little care with 0 depending on what you believe $val(0)$ is).

Comment: @KReiser I think I understand. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$g(a) = 0$ if and only if $g$ is in the maximal ideal of $k[X]$ generated by $(X-a)$.  You can conclude from here that $\mathcal O_a(V)$ is exactly the localization of $k[X]$ at the maximal ideal $(X-a)$.  Since $k[X]$ is a principal ideal domain, it is a Dedekind domain, so all its localizations at maximal ideals are discrete valuation rings.

You can argue directly that $\mathcal O_a(V)$ is a DVR as follows: every $g \in k[X]$ can be written uniquely as $(X-a)^n h(X)$, where $n \geq 0$ and $h(a) \neq 0$.  Moreover $g \in \langle X-a \rangle$ if and only if $n \geq 1$.  This implies that every nonzero element of $\mathcal O_a(V)$ can be written as $\frac{f(X)}{h(X)} (X-a)^n$, where $n \geq 0$ and $f(a), h(a) \neq 0$.

Comment: Perfectly clear. Thank you so much!

Comment: @D_S, why " every $g \in k[X]$ can be written uniquely as $(X-a)^n h(X)$, where $n \geq 0$ and $h(a) \neq 0$."?

Comment: It follows from the definition of localization and the fact that $k[X]$ is a principal ideal domain.  If you ask it as a separate question, I'll answer it

Comment: @D_S I think he had the same problem as me. To anyone else in the future that got absolutely tripped up by this fact, notice that it is $n\geq 0$ NOT $n\geq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to prove that $\mathfrak{m}_a(V)$ is principal. But this is straightforward since $\mathscr{O}_a(V)$ is nothing but the localization of $k[x]$ at $(x-a)$.